# Отправить результат работы кода по электронной почте

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне собрать результат данного кода в одну переменную и отправить по почте? Сейчас `print(mac)` на экран выводит все что нужно, но на почту отправляется только последняя строка.

[image: картинка]

```
    if '.194.249' in output:
        print("Pool забит")
        for line in ip_mac_lines:
            if '0100' not in line:
                ok = line.split()
                f = operator.itemgetter(1)
                okk = str(f(ok))
                okk = okk.replace("'", "")
                okk = re.sub(r'[\(\)]', '', str(okk))
                okk = okk.replace(".", "")
                if '01' in okk:
                    okk = okk[2:]
                    # print(okk)
                    mac = ':'.join(okk[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(okk), 2))
                    #print(mac)
                    msg[
                        'Subject'] = f'В некоторых магазинах {day}.{month}.{year} забился пул IP-адресов.'  # Тема сообщения
                    body = f"На ядре {hostname} забился пул IP-адресов. Просьба обратить внимание на следующих клиентов, получивших некорректные ip-адреса в vlan 194: \n {mac}\n\n"
```

Comment: предполагаю что вы отправляете письмо  после цикла. И туда просто передаете последнее значение `msg` и `body`.

Comment: #print(mac) выводит все правильно. Но на почту  отправляется только последняя строка (последний мак адрес)

Comment: у тебя все вопросы на одну и ту же тему с разных сторон. За столько времени уже можно разобраться.

Comment: осталось только на почту отправить.

Comment: потому что print(mac) выводит каждый раз, а отправляется только один раз после цикла. И после цикла там только одно - последнее - значение. Отправляй в каждой итерации, будет отправляться все.

Answer (score 0):

надеюсь поймешь в чем разница).

```
my_ip = ['1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2','3.3.3.3']

for el in my_ip:
   msg = f'bad ip {el}'

print(msg)

print('----------')
msg_all = []

for el in my_ip:
   msg_all.append(f'bad ip {el}')
   
print('\n'.join(msg_all))
```

P.S.  Ну или если вам нужно отправить столько писем сколько `mac` то тогда, как сказали в комментариях, отправляйте сообщение каждую итерацию

Comment: Мне нужно все маки в одном письме отправлять.

Comment: @Holmes  в примере выше так и есть.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Проблема решена.